# Issues mixing textures when using a mask with 3 channels and alpha

Tags: opengl, shader, fragment-shader

I have a png with transparency with plane colors so I can later replace them with a texture in a shader, like this

[image]

I use each color channel to know the amount of what texture I need to use. Fox example I use red to draw sand and use blue for water.

[image]

I get the above result with this shader

```
vec4 board = texture(texture_3, texture_position);

vec4 ground_color = texture(texture_4, texture_position_gamma);
color = ground_color;

if (board.g > 0) {
    vec4 grass_color = texture(texture_5, texture_position_delta);
    color = mix(color, grass_color, max(0, board.a - board.r - board.b));
}
if (board.r > 0) {
    vec4 sand_color = texture(texture_6, texture_position_gamma);
    color = mix(color, sand_color, max(0, board.a - board.g - board.b));
}
if (board.b > 0) {
    vec4 water_color = vec4(0.1, 0.6, 0.6, 1);
    color = mix(color, water_color, board.a * board.b);
}
```

I think it looks mostly okay but I can see some artifacts, like the sand being too strong when the water and grass is drawn in the same pixel. You can see what I mean in this screenshot:

[image]

Is my approach okay or I'm doing something wrong with the mixing?

Comment: Which filtering are you using? Mipmaps won't work because the texture lookups are in non uniform control flow.

Comment: Have you tried applying the alpha channel after mixing the colors? Also, in what order do you intend to blend the layers (e.g. send -> grass -> water)?

Comment: @dev.bmax the order I want is from bottom to top grass -> sand -> water, how do you suggest applying the alpha channel?

Comment: @BDL I'm using mipmaps and the filtering is 

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB);
glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 255);

Comment: If you interpret different color channels of the board as "alpha" values of your layers (grass, sand, water), then I would expect the blended color calculation to be something like this: `water_color * water_alpha + (sand_color * sand_alpha + grass_color * grass_alpha * (1 - sand_alpha)) * (1 - water_alpha)` where `water_alpha` would be `board.b` in your case. And the fragment color would be `vec4(blended_color, board.a)`.